# Error while using promisefiy all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use promisifyAll to the following module since I want to use it with promises and I got error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

```
const DBWrapper = Promise.promisifyAll(require("node-dbi").DBWrapper);

        var dbWrapper = new DBWrapper('pg', dbConnectionConfig);
        dbWrapper.connect();


        dbWrapper.insert('USERS', data, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error to insert data: " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("test" + data);
            }

        }).then(() => {

            //read data
            dbWrapper.fetchAll("SELECT * FROM USERS", null, function (err, result) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("Data came back from the DB.", result);
                } else {
                    console.log("DB returned an error: %s", err);
                }

                dbWrapper.close(function (close_err) {
                    if (close_err) {
                        console.log("Error while disconnecting: %s", close_err);
                    }
                });
            });

        })
```

Comment: method with promises after promisifyall have `Ascyn` suffix: `insertAsync`, `fetchAllAsync`

Comment: Why are you still passing callbacks if you want to use promises???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things going on here that are incorrect from what I can tell.

1. You're not properly implementing the promises in the above code. Error first callbacks aren't passed in when invoking Promise returning methods, instead they pass the result value to the nearest `.then()`. If an error occurs they will pass that to the nearest `.catch()`. If there is no `.catch()` and an error occurs, an `unhandledRejection` error will be thrown.
2. By default, `promisifyAll()` appends the suffix `Async` to any promisified methods, so you will need to modify any method calls on `dbWrapper` accordingly.

Assuming `node-dbi` can be promisifed and that your DB calls are correct the following code should work as you were initially anticipating

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const DBWrapper = require("node-dbi").DBWrapper;

const dbWrapper = Promise.promisifyAll(new DBWrapper('pg', dbConnectionConfig));

return dbWrapper.insertAsync('USERS', data)
    .then((data) => {      
        console.log("test" + data);

        //read data
        return dbWrapper.fetchAllAsync("SELECT * FROM USERS", null)
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('Data came back from DB.', result);

        return dbWrapper.closeAsync();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred:', err);
    });
```

Comment: :Thanks I try it out but I got error :TypeError: dbWrapper.insertAsync is not a function  , any idea?

Comment: @RaynD I've updated my answer, after looking at the `node-dbi` code, you'll need to do your `promisifyAll()` on the *instance* of `DBWrapper`. This is because `new` creates an instance of `DBWrapper` and the protoype for `DBWrapper` doesn't actually have the promisified versions of the functions, so we need to `promisifyAll()` the *instance* of `DBWrapper` and not `DBWrapper` itself.